# Why doesn't this .htaccess work?

Tags: .htaccess, unix

I have setup 'dokuwiki' to my Server.
It's stored in `/usr/share/wiki` folder.
So the path is `/usr/share/wiki/doku.php`

When I access to http://example.com/wiki/start, I get 404 Not found.

What's wrong with my .htaccess?
I doubt if there's something wrong with **RewriteBase**

**.htaccess**

```
## Enable this to restrict editing to logged in users only
 
## You should disable Indexes and MultiViews either here or in the
## global config. Symlinks maybe needed for URL rewriting.
#Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
 
## make sure nobody gets the htaccess files
<Files ~ "^[\._]ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
 
## Uncomment these rules if you want to have nice URLs using
## $conf['userewrite'] = 1 - not needed for rewrite mode 2
RewriteEngine on
#
## Not all installations will require the following line.  If you do,
## change "/dokuwiki" to the path to your dokuwiki directory relative
## to your document root.
RewriteBase /wiki
#
## If you enable DokuWikis XML-RPC interface, you should consider to
## restrict access to it over HTTPS only! Uncomment the following two
## rules if your server setup allows HTTPS.
RewriteCond % !=on
RewriteRule ^lib/exe/xmlrpc.php$      https://%% [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^_media/(.*)              lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_detail/(.*)             lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_export/([^/]+)/(.*)     doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$                        doku.php  [L]
RewriteCond %       !-f
RewriteCond %       !-d
RewriteRule (.*)                      doku.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$               doku.php
```

**etc/httpd/conf.d**

```
# enter the following in pico
Alias /wiki/ "/usr/share/wiki/"
Alias /wiki "/usr/share/wiki/"
<Directory "/usr/share/wiki/" >
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from none

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews


# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

or use line below at last

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

sorry for delay..

Answer (score 0):

Is it working properly on your localhost?

If yes you have to modify the **.htaccess** according to your hosting server.

because many times the hosting servers may hosts more than one sites. And they are having different **.htacces** accordingly.

Comment: This is on VPS and yes I have root authirity so I am using other .htaccess in other folder too.

Comment: remove the wiki from **RewriteBase** and try again.. i am not sure but it could help

Comment: I tried that now `Not Found
The requested URL /wiki/goats was not found on this server.`

Comment: **#Fix Rewrite

Options -Multiviews



# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]** 
or use this 
**RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]** 
at the last line

Comment: Could you please put that in you Answer?

Comment: I updated my question. I had a conf file, does it affect to this issue?